# Southsun instance solo mission repeatable?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Is the soushsun solo mission instance repeatable, and can I also get the rewards again? After finishing it, I would like to do it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is repeatable, but the reward is only given once per account.

For a few hours it was per character, but players exploited it, so it was quickly patched. ([source](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/livingworld/southsun/Daily-Reward-for-Canachs-Lair/first#post2110342))

Comment: I noticed that on [Dulfy's site](http://dulfy.net/2013/05/28/gw2-canachs-lair-and-subdirector-null-guide/), she lists the reward for the solo mission as being account-bound and a one-time only. Your source mentions repeating it by deleting and remaking characters, but doesn't mention repeating it daily. Have you tested it to be sure that it is repeatable every day?

Comment: I saw that Dulfy has it listed as a one-time reward too. Since it has only been out for a little more than a day, and the rewards have been patched at least once since then, it is hard to tell. The OP on my source claims that it is daily, but the devs don't confirm or deny. Patch notes make it sound like it was never possible to get more than one per account. I think Dulfy is actually right that it is once per account now, and that explorable is daily per account. I'll modify my answer to keep up with incoming information.